# Elasticsearch Java high level client closing connections

Tags: java, elasticsearch, database-connection

I'm just the High Level client, reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-getting-started-initialization.html

It talks about closing connections but the documentation is a bit ambiguous about when to close connections. It asks to close connection when you are "truly done with it".

If I'm integration this in my webserver that does heavy reads and writes to elasticsearch, do I close after every request or is it only to be cleared when the server reloads? If I close after every request, wouldn't that be a lot of overhead to create connections for every request.

Comment: only close at server bounce, close es rest client == shutdown apache http client  == kill the connection pool, and that's expensive.

Comment: @fasttooth The Server Bounce control is automatic? However, When i do not use a long period of time and than use the REST Client, it make "connection error".